# Delphi Barcode recognition and positioning

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, barcode, zxing

I'm using ZXing library (https://github.com/Spelt/ZXing.Delphi) in my Delphi FMX app on Android and Windows. It works by returning the barcode as text from a cam image. Now I need to know **where** on the image the recognized barcode is to draw a rectangle around it. An x/y position with length and height, even approximately, would be helpful. Is there any property that I missed till now? Or even another library that gives me that information from an image?

[EDIT]
I found an array named resultPoints.  After a sucessfull recognition attempt, there is at least one item within that has an x/y property. But it does not seem to be the upper left corner of the barcode or something like that.

Comment: ZXing.Common.DetectorResult.pas mentions returning _points of interest in the image, like the location of finder patterns or corners of the barcode in the image_.